# template not loading using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, angularjs-templates

I learned about ng-include and used it for templates but I am not able to include the page.

The index.html and menu.html are in the same directory and menu.html is to be loaded in index.html

```
<ng-include src="'menu.html'"></ng-include>
```

I have included the app's name in index.html. 
I want to include menu.html between header and footer. So I have deleted everything in the menu.html except the container div which I want to include. The links and references have also been properly set in index.html

I am really stuck here. Please help me out! Thanks.

**edit:**
Here is my project structure -

```
Project-
       app-
           fonts-...
           images-...
           scripts-
                   app.js
                   controllers.js
                   services.js
           styles-...
           index.html
           menu.html
       ...
```

**edit -2**

I just found out that when I change my browser, i.e. from chrome to firefox, it loads successfully! Now why is this happening?

Comment: can you please try `ng-include` as `<div ng-include=" 'menu.html' "></div>`

Comment: @Maher tried it. Still the same.

Comment: OK, so now let see your app structure, can you please improve your question by add it to the question?

Comment: Another way you can do, it's set the url from the root of your app, for example `ng-include=" '/Application/vendor/menu.html' "`

Comment: Did you checked your console please, any message or error?

Comment: @Maher here, angular.js:11048 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///H:/0000/MEAN/mini%20projects/Frontend/Project/app/menu.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.


​

Comment: Do you use `localhost` or run app(index.html) directly on browser?

Comment: directly on the browser @Maher

Comment: Cross origin mean you try to load something from other server, if you run your app with local `IIS`, your `ng-include` run perfectly, you have to run the app as `http://localhost/your-app-name` or `http://localhost:2365/your-app-name`

Comment: @Maher Ok.. thanks. I think I'll have to research some more.. Anyways, thanks for your time. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a webserver ?

from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

> In addition, the browser's Same Origin Policy and Cross-Origin
>   Resource Sharing (CORS) policy may further restrict whether the
>   template is successfully loaded. For example, ngInclude won't work for
>   cross-domain requests on all browsers and for file:// access on some
>   browsers.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Because after changing my browser, it worked fine. I am new in this field so can you pls explain in a simpler way what happened? Why chrome didn't worked whereas firefox did. And what thing I should keep in mind for the future, because such things are difficult to find!